# SSH Script runs fine manually running it but does not when exec with PHP remotely

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

### Summary

I've created a shell script that is uploaded via SFTP using the `phpseclib3` library. The shell script is being executed, but all of the `apt` packages are not being installed when running the script using the below PHP Code. It installs some packages, but hangs up on one somewhere. However, if I use FileZilla to upload the file using the same user, and then login to execute the same script all packages are being installed correctly. The output is not showing any errors either.

It's almost like the packages are all trying to be created once which is locking the packages up and causing an error that I can't find.

### Things I've tried

- Have the script run silently
- Made sure that PHP isn't timing out
- Used a different SSH composer package
- Splitting the apt install into individual items instead of one long list
- Added and removed `sudo true` to the top of the script
- Tried to re-run `apt install` multiple times
- Use `apt-get` instead of `apt`

### PHP Code

```
$ssh = new SSH2($ip_address);
if (!$ssh->login('login', $key)) {
  // error handling
}

$ssh->setTimeout(0);
$ssh->setKeepAlive(10);

$process[] = $ssh->exec('chmod +x install.sh; sh install.sh;');
```

### Shell Example

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo true

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update

sudo apt -y install curl wget file tar bzip2 gzip unzip bsdmainutils python util-linux ca-certificates binutils bc jq tmux netcat lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6

echo steam steam/license note '' | sudo debconf-set-selections && echo steam steam/question select 'I AGREE' | sudo debconf-set-selections && sudo apt -y install steamcmd

wget -O linuxgsm.sh https://linuxgsm.sh && chmod +x linuxgsm.sh && bash linuxgsm.sh squadserver

yes Y | ./squadserver install

touch done.txt
```

### Error Log

```
 sudo true
+ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
+ sudo apt update

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Get:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Hit:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [902 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages [13.5 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [973 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [9208 B]
Get:9 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1007 kB]
Get:10 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9156 B]
Get:11 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages [8531 kB]
Get:12 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages [144 kB]
Get:13 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [1197 kB]
Get:14 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [20.2 kB]
Get:15 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1555 kB]
Get:16 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:17 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main i386 Packages [10.0 kB]
Get:18 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages [10.3 kB]
Fetched 14.6 MB in 11s (1370 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
74 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
+ sudo apt -y install curl wget file tar bzip2 gzip unzip bsdmainutils python util-linux ca-certificates binutils bc jq tmux netcat lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
+ sudo debconf-set-selections
+ echo steam steam/license note ''
+ sudo debconf-set-selections
+ echo steam steam/question select 'I AGREE'
+ sudo apt -y install steamcmd

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Comment: whats the error (both error code and error messages) returned from `$ssh->exec(...)`?

Comment: @pynexj I don't see any errors, the packages are just not being installed. I only saw at one point `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` but it seems more like a side-effect of the issue and not the issue itself.

Comment: you can try something like `$ssh->exec('bash -x install.sh >& install.log')` and see whats in the log file.

Comment: @pynexj I'll give that a go and see what I come up with. I just don't understand why manually running the script would work but if PHP does the exact same thing there is an issue.

Comment: not sure if your script requires to be run on a tty. try allocating a pty for the ssh connection.

Comment: @pynexj I added the error log if you don't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from this portion of the code:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update
```

For whatever reason it was creating a lock file which was killing the other processes after it. To fix it, I just removed the lock and reconfigured dpkg by adding this portion of code after the update.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```